Calendar.current.dateComponents() return milliseconds
I'm using Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: .now, to: timerEnd) to return the end time for a timer within my app. The issue I'm having is that I want to display milliseconds after the remaining times is less than a second. The following code works but I do not like having to run calculations on nanoseconds directly in my call, I would rather just be able to use timeToEnd.milliseconds
let timeToEnd = Calendar.current.dateComponents(
    [.second, .nanosecond], 
    from: .now, 
    to: timerEnd // Just a Date() object
)

return "\((timeToEnd.nanosecond! / 1000000))"

Is there a way I can just extend Date or Calendar to access timeToEnd.milliseconds?

As a technical detail, I do not believe that Date guarantees “monotonically increasing values” from repeated calls. If you are really worried about millisecond-level accuracy, you might consider (in legacy codebases, at least) using some mach_absolute_time based solution like CACurrentMediaTime. Or, nowadays, we might reach for ContinuousClock.

@Rob Thank you for the additional details, it really doesn't have to be pin-point accurate. I just want it accurate enough so my timer doesn't say "0s" and instead lets the user know it's still running until it ends.

Are you really only looking for the seconds between two dates (and not, for example, hours and minutes, too)? If so, timeToEnd.timeIntervalSince(.now), akin to what DuncanC proposed, is the more streamlined solution. But if you really have a compelling use for DateComponents, e.g., you’re fetching not just seconds, but minutes and hours (or whatever), too, then RobNapier’s extension is a great approach. It just depends.

You would extend DateComponents:
extension DateComponents {
    var millisecond: Int? { 
        guard let nanosecond else { return nil }
        return nanosecond / 1_000_000
    }
}


Well that was simple, thanks!

Of course that code is still "run[nig] calculations on nanoseconds". It's just hides the work in an extension.
If the concern is CPU time, this solution is not going to be any faster.
Using Double seconds and multiplying thay by 1000 would be slightly better since multiplication s faster than division

I think the concern was need to type it out, not the math. I'm not certain if converting to Double and the multiplying and then converting back to Int is actually faster than Int division. Int division is pretty fast. But I don't think that's the point here.

In fact Int division is VERY fast, and type conversion tends to be slow, so if speed is your issue (notwithstanding the issue of premature optimization) this approach is likely to be quite fast.

DateComponents seems like the wrong way to handle this. Date has a built-in function timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate that gives you a Double value for the date.
timerEnd.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate -  Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate would give you the number of seconds remaining until your timer ends, as a Double including a decimal value.
You could multiply that by 1000 to express it in milliseconds, or strip away the integer part of the result and multiply the fraction by 1000 if you only want to know the fractional part of the time remaining expressed in milliseconds.

@Rob would not be "premature" at all since if someone cares about milliseconds, they probably want their code to be very efficient. But this is not even an optimization: it's pointing OP to a proper API. Main reason Calendar.current.dateComponents exists is to help date and time "evaluated in a calendar system and time zone". None of it is in this use case. Here the OP wants to deal with time interval relative to a reference date" - textbook case for Date.

On a modern device worrying about floating point performance is almost always pointless.  I was talking about the fact that DateComponents is doing calendrical calculations, which are not relevant here, and may even yield unexpected results in boundary cases. Under the covers, a Date is a Double offset from the Cocoa epoch date. Doing math on the fractional part of those Doubles is clean, simple, and easy.

Re-reading the original question, I now notice (which you clearly caught quicker than I did) that they’re using date components to only retrieve the seconds between two dates. You are absolutely right that, in that scenario, just getting the TimeInterval between them is absolutely the right approach (though I might suggest timeToEnd.timeIntervalSince(.now)). I was focusing on the “I’m using date components and want milliseconds, too” aspect of the question (which is a common work-around the DateComponentsFormatter limitations), and missed that he was fetching only seconds. Good catch.

Another version Rob Napier’s solution (+1), using flatMap:
extension DateComponents {
    var millisecond: Int? {
        nanosecond.flatMap { $0 / 1_000_000 }
    }
}

If you are unfamiliar with flatMap, Rob Napier’s solution will undoubtedly feel more natural and you should run with it. But I personally reach for flatMap whenever I have an expression that should only be evaluated if an Optional is not nil.
